# Dockerfile build - possible to ignore error?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've got a Dockerfile. When building the image, the build fails on this error:

```
automake: error: no 'Makefile.am' found for any configure output
Error build: The command [/bin/sh -c aclocal && autoconf && automake -a] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

which in reality is harmless. The library builds fine, but Docker stops the build once it receives this error. Is there any way I can instruct Docker to just ignore this?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Sure.  Docker is just responding to the error codes returned by the `RUN` shell scripts in the `Dockerfile`.  If your `Dockerfile` has something like:

```
RUN make
```

You could replace that with:

```
RUN make; exit 0
```

This will always return a `0` (success) exit code.  The disadvantage here is that your image will appear to build successfully even if there *are* actual errors in the build process.

Comment: I've came here when trying to run `service php7-fpm start`. It would return 1 and RUN would fail; using `service php7-fpm start; service php7-fpm status` does the trick - it seems to solve a problem during build as well, since both commands running separate would give trouble.

Comment: I've come here when trying to build Qt5 from source. It would build just fine, but using concurrent build combined with the fact that Qt build process has build-time tests run from make (that intentionally fail) my RUN command exited with error (2). This hopefully will solve the problem!

Comment: Ah Laravel composer install now forcing people to run... whatever..

Comment: What if we want to use `COPY` instead of `RUN`?! For example, ignoring that the src/dest file exists or not.

Comment: Copy the parent directory of your file/directory into the container, then use a script in a `RUN` statement to check for specific files and place them where appropriate.

Answer (score 66):

This might be of interest to those, whose potential errors in their images are **not harmless enough** *to go unnoticed/logged*. (Also, not enough rep. to comment, so here as an answer.)

As pointed out, the disadvantage of `RUN make; exit 0` is you don't get to know, if your build failed. Hence, rather use something like:

```
make test 2>&1 > /where/ever/make.log || echo "There were failing tests!"
```

Like this, you get notified via the docker image build process log, and you can see what exactly went bad during `make` (or whatsoever else execution, this is not restricted to make).

Comment: This is waaay underrated answer. My use case was some package lists not reachable and `apt-get update -y` was failing.

Answer (score 55):

You can also use the standard bash ignore error `|| true`, which is nice if you are in the middle of a chain:

```
RUN <first stage> && <job that might fail> || true && <next stage>
```

Comment: just what i needed :) what would be even more better is to fail if job failed, but after next stage (cleanup)

Comment: I actually need that because I know that specific job (dpkg) will fail, and the next step 'apt-get install -f' will fix all the missing dependencies.