# Skip error in dockerfile during the build

Tags: docker, jenkins-docker

Just wonder if theres a better way to skip a command that could fail (because I'm using jenkins to build and deploy the application)

Now I'm doing something like this

```
RUN unlink /run/supervisor.sock && etc/init.d/supervisor stop || echo "supervisor was not started"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is a typical linux trick to ensure a zero exit code

```
RUN unlink /run/supervisor.sock && etc/init.d/supervisor stop || :
```

the answer given here essentially uses different syntax to achieve the same

[Dockerfile build - possible to ignore error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716937/dockerfile-build-possible-to-ignore-error)

there is no other way of preventing build failure at present