# How can I force cancel dockerbuild using bash a command?

Tags: bash, docker

The reason why I'm asking is because we're using AWS codebuild & I need to do DB migrations. If a DB migration breaks, I want to cancel the codebuild & rollback the migration which was just made. I've got this part working, all I need to do now is cancel the dockerbuild mid way. How can I do this?

This is my .sh file with the knex migration commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running"
function mytest {
    "$@"
    local status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        knex migrate:rollback 
      echo "Rolling back knex migrate $1" >&2
      exit
    fi
    return $status
}

mytest knex migrate:latest
```

Running `exit` will not cancel/break the docker build.

My Dockerfile (just incase):

```
FROM node:6.2.0

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/migrate.sh
RUN /usr/src/app/migrate.sh


EXPOSE 8080

CMD npm run build && npm start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Running exit will not cancel/break the docker build.

running `exit 1` should

Docker should respond to the error codes returned by the `RUN` shell scripts in said Dockerfile.

Comment: Great! I looked everywhere and couldn't find anything. I was close though

Comment: @James111 yes, you have a similar case (for an opposite effect) in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30717108/6309

Comment: Good to know :) If this isn't documented somewhere on the docker page, I think it should. I can see it coming in handy for a multitude of uses :D