# Stop docker when run command returns error code?

Tags: docker

How do you tell Docker to stop executing a Dockefile when one of its RUN commands returns an error code?

I have a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt install -yq `cat requirements.txt | tr "\\n" " "`
RUN ./some_other_setup.sh
RUN ./my_tests.sh
```

and occasionally the `apt install` will fail if there's a brief network outage. However, the Docker will continue executing the other RUN commands, even though they too will fail because they depend on the `apt install` succeeding.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716937/dockerfile-build-possible-to-ignore-error/30717108) answer, I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Some `apt` errors are in fact Warning messages that still return the exit code as `0`. Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175146/218771) question, it gives many options to catch these warnings and manipulate the exit code base on them.

Comment: @FedericoMoya Isn't that the opposite of what I'm asking? I want Docker to stop on an error and it isn't. That question's saying they don't want Docker to stop on an error but it is.

Comment: Any time the command executed by `RUN` returns a non-zero exit code, the build will stop. Make sure you chain your commands with `&&` rather than `;`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch error and stop you can do like linux script

```
RUN set -e && apt install -yq `cat requirements.txt | tr "\\n" " "`
```

so `set -e` will catch all errors and stop if any happened.

OR

you can prevent failing `apt install` by adding `RUN apt-get install -f` which will install missing dependencies.

Also if `apt-get/apt install` has any errors you can do

```
apt-get install [your stuff] || true
```

which will always pass even with errors and then you do `apt-get install -f` so you always have all dependencies needed