# piped sh command causing docker build script to choke

Tags: docker, sh

I've got this in a docker build file: `RUN 'echo "y" | /usr/bin/task'`

When building, this error is thrown:

```
 => ERROR [tool_config  9/11] RUN 'echo "y" | /usr/bin/task'                                                                             0.2s
------
 > [tool_config  9/11] RUN 'echo "y" | /usr/bin/task':
#15 0.164 /bin/sh: echo "y" | /usr/bin/task: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c 'echo "y" | /usr/bin/task']: exit code: 127
```

The command runs fine when manually run from insside the container. The `task` command is definitely installed.

Without without quotes, `RUN echo "y" | task` gives:

```
 => ERROR [tool_config  9/11] RUN echo "y" | /usr/bin/task                                                                               0.2s
------
 > [tool_config  9/11] RUN echo "y" | /usr/bin/task:
#15 0.176 A configuration file could not be found in /root
#15 0.176
#15 0.176 Would you like a sample /root/.taskrc created, so Taskwarrior can proceed? (yes/no) No matches.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c echo "y" | /usr/bin/task]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: I don't want to be that guy, but can you double-check again to ensure that `/usr/bin/task` exists in that specific build step (build step no. 9)? You can cross-reference with a command that should be guaranteed to work: `echo "y" | /usr/bin/base64`

Comment: I get the same error with /usr/bin/base64

Comment: The entire `RUN` command is in single quotes, which causes the shell to interpret it as a single shell word – the spaces and pipe are part of the filename it's looking for.  Does deleting the outermost quotes help?

Comment: Tried that, but I'll update OP as the output is slightly different.

Comment: OK, I think I know what's happening. The `task` command is returning "no matches" because there are no tasks created yet which is showing as an error code causing docker to check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `task` command was returning "No matches" because no tasks had yet been created so the command exited with an error code of `1` and docker choked.

Fix is simple as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/30717108/1641112:

`RUN echo "y" | task; exit 0;`